# Getting Parameter Group name from AWS CDK Python rds.ParameterGroup

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I'm building a RDS Parameter Group via Python CDK:

```
mygroup = rds.ParameterGroup(self,'blah',
   description="my description",
   engine=something,
   parameters={
     something
}
```

My question is, how do I name and get the name of the parameter group created. There doesn't seem to be a way to name it or use the name against another CFN construct.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

To access the name, use the underlying CloudFormation resource's [`ref` function:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-dbparametergroup.html#aws-properties-rds-dbparametergroup-return-values)

`mygroup.node.default_child.ref`

Generally, though, if you're using L2 constructs, you shouldn't need to access the name directly.